# Coding A Valid Unordered List

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c-validation

Trying to have my website w3 clean and using this website to do the validations http://validator.w3.org/. The problem is I am having trouble with my unordered lists. Here is the site to view the full source code on your own: http://gmustudent.com. Here is an example of the unordered list

```
<div id="mainToolbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="firstTab"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="search?tag=J2EE">J2EE</a>
        <li><a href="search?tag=Javascript">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="search?tag=AJAX">AJAX</a></li>
        <li><a href="search?tag=Dreamweaver">Dreamweaver</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/GMUStudentDesign" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">YouTube</a></li>
        <li class="lastTab"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is an example of the error I am getting. Any ides on what I am doing wrong?

```
Error Line 26, Column 9: document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol" start-tag
<li><a href="search?tag=Javascript">Javascript</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second list element is missing the closing `</li>`

Comment: @gmustudent, it’s a problem just because you asked for it by declaring an XHTML doctype. ☺ In real-life HTML as implemented in browsers, the end tag `</li>` is always optional.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `li` tag here:

```
<li><a href="search?tag=J2EE">J2EE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a missing closin  on the second list item...Most likely all w3 corrections will have to do with these things